# Elevating a Gas Hot Water Heater

Tags: water, heater

We just bought a major fixer-upper, our gas hot water heater is in an unfinished basement (storm cellar) on a dirt floor with nothing protecting the bottom and providing for runoff.  We do have a tube we installed from release valve which extends almost to the floor just in case.  We would like to elevate the HWH to protect it from surrounding dirt and provide for runoff.  What do you suggest?

Comment: In many jurisdictions gas water heaters in garages are required to be on a stand 18 inches above the floor. I don't know about basements. But if you would put it on a stand on your dirt floor you would have to have a concrete pad under it to prevent tipping due to the legs going down into the dirt. See http://www.homedepot.com/p/Eastman-21-in-D-x-21-25-in-W-x-18-in-H-Water-Heater-Stand-86278/205365245?MERCH=REC-_-PIPHorizontal1_rr-_-205762992-_-205365245-_-N

Answer (score 3):

You don't necessarily need to elevate it to protect it from the dirt.  They make a water heater drain pain http://www.homedepot.com/p/24-in-Plastic-Water-Heater-Drain-Pan-15021/204834496 for this purpose.  (I have no affiliation with home depot, they just have a conveniently searchable site).  They're 1) cheap 2) solve your problem and 3) have a hose fitting to attach a line to your sump pit or floor drain.